# How to fetch laravel data without page refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently working for real time chat module by laravel. I am able to send user chat data to database by ajax however, can not able to display data from database without refresh.

Here is the place to display message that comes from database-

```
        <ul class="convo-list convo-body">
      <li>
        <div class="row convo-row-msg">
          <div class="col-xs-2 convo-row-msg-avatar">
              <a href="{{ url('/') }}/images/users/photos/profiles/{{ $users->profilephoto }}">  
                <img src="{{url('/') }}/images/users/photos/profiles/{{ $users->profilephoto }}" alt="" width="220px" style="border: 4px solid #fff;border-radius:2px;">
              </a>
          </div>  
          <div class="col-xs-10 convo-row-body">
            <b><a href="#"> Username place here </a> </b>
            <span class="timestamp">
              Timestamp
            </span>
            <p class="convo-content"> User chat message will be there </p>
          </div>
        </div>          
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my ajax that I need to grab from database-

```
var takeHash = $('#hash').val();
var interval = setInterval(function(){

$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: takeHash, 
    success: function(response) {

        $('.convo-body').append(response);

    }
});

}, 1000);
```

Finally my controller response like that way-

```
    public function showSingleMessage($hash)
{
    $msg = Message::where('conversationhash', $hash)
                    ->where('fromid', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->get();
    $fromid = '';
    foreach ($msg as $value) {            
        $fromid = $value->fromid;
    }

    $messages = Message::where('conversationhash', $hash)
        ->Where('fromid', Auth::user()->id)
        ->orWhere('fromid', $fromid)
        ->get();

    $user = new User();
    return view('messages.show-single')
        ->with(['messages' => $messages, 'user' => $user, 'touser' => $fromid]);
}
```

So, can anyone help me how to display my data in blade template (laravel use that)?

```js
var takeHash = $('#hash').val();
var interval = setInterval(function(){

$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: takeHash, 
    success: function(response) {

        $('.convo-body').append(response);

    }
});

}, 1000);
```

```html
<ul class="convo-list convo-body">
      <li>
        <div class="row convo-row-msg">
          <div class="col-xs-2 convo-row-msg-avatar">
              <a href="{{ url('/') }}/images/users/photos/profiles/{{ $users->profilephoto }}">  
                <img src="{{url('/') }}/images/users/photos/profiles/{{ $users->profilephoto }}" alt="" width="220px" style="border: 4px solid #fff;border-radius:2px;">
              </a>
          </div>  
          <div class="col-xs-10 convo-row-body">
            <b><a href="#"> Username place here </a> </b>
            <span class="timestamp">
              Timestamp
            </span>
            <p class="convo-content"> User chat message will be there </p>
          </div>
        </div>          
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: in jsFiddle, cannot run PHP code. However, I just placed there html and javascript code.....

https://jsfiddle.net/twcwfy2w/

Comment: Better approach for integrating real time chat is XMPP.
Otherwise you need to create a script that will check the update in db and made the changes in view at a shorter interval of time.

Comment: Yes, I already use `setInterval` for 1 secd to fetch that data. All the things are working. 

Now, I need to know how to integrate many data in organised way in view page that comes database?

Comment: Is there any way to use any kind of templates for jQuery where I can set my php, jquery data and finally that template will be replaced to html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not conformed about your output data so i just updated the append format in user screen.

```
$.ajax({  
type: 'GET',  
url: takeHash, 
success: function(response) {
 appenddata='<li>';
    if (typeof(response)=='array') {
     appenddata+=response['message'];
   }
  if ( typeof(response)=='object') {
     appenddata+=response->message;
   }
   if ( typeof(response)=='string') {
     appenddata+=response;
   }
     appenddata+='</li>';
    $('.convo-body').append(appenddata);

}
});

}, 1000);
```

Comment: TQ for your answer... actually my message display html code is in the first block of my question. I need to display all of my return data there... that is the problem that I need to solve...

Comment: so use jquery foreach
array.forEach(function(currentValue,index,arr), thisValue)

Comment: i need example data format of your chat output on ajax call for clarification